# react native android network request fail, but work on ios and postman

Tags: react-native, expo

I got a api that runs well on ios device, ios simulator and postman. But it fail to work with android device and android emulator.

this is my api `https://a.com/proxy/done` post method

This is how I do it in the app

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        let res = await fetch('https://a.com/proxy/done', {
            method: 'post',
        })
            console.log('res', res)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
    }
}
```

This piece of code runs well on ios and post man but fail in android, I got this error

```
Network request failed
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/core/whatwg-fetch.js:504:29 in onerror
- node_modules/event-target-shim/lib/event-target.js:172:43 in dispatchEvent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:578:29 in setReadyState
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:392:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:191:12 in emit
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:349:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:106:26 in <unknown>
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:297:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:105:17 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I also tried replace fetch axios, same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is fetch API got some issue with some ssl. option 1 ask the dev op to change certificate type.

option 2 use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob